# Mysql General Log Retrieve BLOB Content

Tags: mysql, database, logging, blob, recovery

Mysql :5.7

General Log: 1

log_output : Table

I have written some code using java to store images in a blob column of a table (**tbl_attachment_mst**).
My General Log settings are turned on and is configured to write to '**table**'.

Whenever i add an image to **tbl_attachment_mst** , mysql does log it in the **mysql.general_log** table with **_binary('some unreadable characters not sure what this is')**.

I have accidently lost contents of the table **tbl_attachment_mst** . Is it possible to recover my data from the mysql.generaL_log table??

I think i am having some issue with the character set while trying to execute the query that is stored in mysql.general_log.

(From comment)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_attachment_mst (
    attachment_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    file_name varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
    created_date datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    activate_flag tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL, 
    file_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    type varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL, 
    attachment_asblob longblob, 
    PRIMARY KEY (attachment_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

insert into tbl_attachment_mst values
     (default,'test.jpg',sysdate(),1,1,'Type',
      _binary('some characters here'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the below set of queries, i was able to get the exact data that was inserted into the db at that particular time.....

```
SELECT argument INTO @sql FROM mysql.general_log limit 1;    
PREPARE sql_query FROM @sql;    
EXECUTE sql_query;
```

These queries would insert the data back into the tbl_attachment_mst...

Answer (score 2):

Grab it fast.  I suspect the general_log, as a table, gets flushed in some fashion pretty fast.

It works just like a table, so `SELECTs` work.  However, your `SELECTs` go into the general log unless you have turned it off.

Recommend doing `SELECT ... HEX(col) ...` to avoid the unprintable characters.

Please provide more details so I can try to simulate it and see what would work best.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
An approximation of the INSERT statement (or whatever was involved)
```

And if the grabbed hex is useful, you can use something like this to reverse the steps:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (...  UNHEX(hex_string) ... )
```

Comment: -- show create table
CREATE TABLE `tbl_attachment_mst` (
  `attachment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `activate_flag` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attachment_asblob` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attachment_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: my insert statement contains  :- insert into tbl_attachment_mst values (default,'test.jpg',sysdate(),1,1,'Type',_binary('some characters here'))

Comment: @Shoaeb - I'm surprised you did not get a syntax error.  `_binary` is an introducer in front of a literal, not a function `()`.  Is there any chance there was a backslash in the string?

Comment: no there wasnt any escape character before _binary...

Comment: I have found a solution to my problem by executing the contents of argument column using mysql itself....
i would hav thought of this before but because of the stress of losing data, i was not able to think properly....